# Load PHP response into DIV after each link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table which is structured as below. Instead of just linking to external PHP scripts, I want the PHP script to be executed in a DIV which appears below the corresponding row. I figured this could be done by inserting a row that spans the table with a DIV in it, and then loading the external script in that DIV.

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr class="tableTitle">
    <td></td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Stock</td>
    <td>Options</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="getProduct.php?id=634">007: Quantum of Solace</a></td>
    <td>Gaming > Xbox 360 > Games > Shooter</td>
    <td>$22.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="productDelete.php?id=634">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="getProduct.php?id=711">2006 FIFA World Cup Germany</a></td>
    <td>Gaming > Xbox 360 > Games > Sports</td>
    <td>$9.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="productDelete.php?id=711">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="getProduct.php?id=148">2010 FIFA World Cup South Africa</a></td>
    <td>Gaming > PlayStation 3</td>
    <td>$15.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="productDelete.php?id=148">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is the jQuery code I tried to make work:

```
$("a").click( function(event) {
    var clicked = $(this);
    $.get($(this).attr('href'),
    function(data){
        $(clicked).next().find('tr').after(data);
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: please use ajax,iframe ,or directly echo from server

Comment: Instead of opening the link in a new window, I want getProduct.php?id=to load in a DIV below the link so the page doesn't have to refresh.

Comment: then please use ajax and replace the content of the div with what you got from server.

Comment: That's what i'm asking for help with. I haven't found any examples on stackoverflow that work with dynamic content (such as this table with a fluctuating number of results).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are saying that you want php inside your html div, here's an example, hope this helps.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "cis246", "t@sk93")
or exit(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db("students",$con)
or die(mysql_error());
$sql = mysql_query("select * from CIS110");
echo "<table cellspacing='0' border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>SID</th><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th></tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) {
$sid = $row -> SID;
$LastName = $row -> LastName;
$firstName = $row -> FirstName;
echo("<tr><td>$sid</td><td>$LastName</td><td>$FirstName</td></tr>");
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: This isn't what I was asking and i've since solved it myself. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to actually execute the PHP script in a document on-demand (with javascript). What you could do is use an iframe and load your document into that, using the `target` attribute of the `a` tag:

```
<a href=somescript.php target=product123>Link</a>
...
<iframe id=product123 frameborder=0></iframe>
```

This'll load the href of the link into the iframe specified by id in the target attribute wihtout any javascript. And remember to hide your iframe somehow (css? js?) until the required link is clicked on. You can also dynamically create and insert iframes when the link is clicked on, but I think this is limited to the same domain.

Comment: This isn't what I was asking and i've since solved it myself. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Well I worked it out myself using Prototype instead of jQuery. Hopefully this will help others.

JavaScript:

```
<script src="js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getDetails(targetDiv) {
        new Ajax.Updater(targetDiv, 'productGet.php', { method: 'get', parameters: 'id='+targetDiv });
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr class="tableTitle">
    <td></td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Stock</td>
    <td>Options</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:getDetails(pid634); return false;">007: Quantum of Solace</a>
      </td>
    <td>Gaming > Xbox 360 > Games > Shooter</td>
    <td>$22.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="productDelete.php?id=634">delete</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5"><div id="pid634"></div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:getDetails(pid711); return false;">2006 FIFA World Cup Germany</a>
            <br>
      <span class="offset">2006 FIFA World Cup</span>
      </td>
    <td>Gaming > Xbox 360 > Games > Sports</td>
    <td>$9.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="productDelete.php?id=711">delete</a>
            <br>
      <a href="productDelete.php?id=711&aliasId=0">delete</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5"><div id="pid711"></div></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:getDetails(pid148); return false;">2010 FIFA World Cup South Africa</a>
      </td>
    <td>Gaming > PlayStation 3</td>
    <td>$15.00</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="productDelete.php?id=148">delete</a>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5"><div id="pid148"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you're using jQuery aswell as Prototype, be sure to avoid any clashes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```